# Alternative Imaging Method for Renal Contrast Media

Tags: medical-imaging, renal

The background of this research isn't important, so I won't waste time on it.

For a portion of my research, I need to assess the capabilities of certain substances as renal contrast agents [basically how well different chemicals work as renal contrast agents] for CAT scans. However, a **major** problem I am facing is that I do not have access to a CT scanning machine.

Is there any way I could assess how well these contrast media work without having the actual CT machine at my disposal?
I understand this question may seem useless, but I really do need an alternative method of testing this. I can allocate up to $1000 dollars for this stage of research

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/30647/7951 and https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/27548/7951